# "Radios" not creating multi options?

Tags: forms, 8

I am creating a radio button like this:

```
$form['paymentMethodSelect'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => $this->t('How would you like to make payment?'),
);
```

This works and creates a single radio button. Now according to documentation, to create multiple radio buttons, you change "radio" to "radios". But if I do that:

```
$form['paymentMethodSelect'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => $this->t('How would you like to make payment?'),
    '#default_value' => 'eft',
    '#options' => [
        'eft' => 'EFT (Electronic Funds Transfer)',
        'cc' => 'Credit Card',
    ],
);
```

But if I do that then I end up with this:

[image]

Any idea why I am not seeing two radio buttons as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Your code still shows radio instead of radios for `'#type'` attribute.

```
$form['paymentMethodSelect'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => $this->t('How would you like to make payment?'),
    '#default_value' => 'eft',
    '#options' => [
        'eft' => 'EFT (Electronic Funds Transfer)',
        'cc' => 'Credit Card',
    ],
);
```

Otherwise there is no other problem I see in your code.
Sample code from D.O

```
$form['settings']['active'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Poll status'),
  '#default_value' => 1,
  '#options' => array(0 => $this->t('Closed'), 1 => $this->t('Active')),
);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my side. But with "radios" I still get the error. Even if I use the exact sample you provided, I also see what is showin in the screenshot. It's like it doesnt understand what "radios" is, and then defaults to what you see there.